# Is it possible to base64 encode the file at a URI?

Tags: php, url, io, base64

I've just been fiddling around with PHP, and I want to know if it's possible to do such a thing.

If so, can you please provide example code?

Update: What I mean, is I want to encode whatever file may be at the URI, not the URI itself. Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: hey, I just asked that question 30 minutes ago, but then deleted it. What a coincidence!

Comment: @think123 oh really? that's weird then...

Comment: Download the file with cURL or similar, then base64 its contents.

Comment: @Brad could you please provide an example?

Comment: @BottleofMilk, could you explain more? Do you want to base64 encode a URL? Or do you want to base64 encode a file? Or do you want to download the file then base64 encode it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://www.google.com'));
```

Comment: +1 same as my answer. I put it on separate lines for clarity.

Comment: Nice! I prefer one liners (for brevity) myself :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why not...

```
<?php $file = file_get_contents("http://example.com/myfile.txt");
      $encoded = base64_encode($file);
```

Answer (score 2):

[**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function will grab the HTML of given URL and [**base64_encode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) function will encode it.

```
<?php 
    $content = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
    $encodedContent = base64_encode($content);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to base64-encode a URL? Simple...

```
base64_encode($uri)
```

Comment: no, I want to base64 encode the file at a URL, so for example `http://www.google.com`, I want to base64 encode the page.